# File encryption in WinRT

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime

I'm current working on a metro application (C#/XAML) that requires file encryption. 
In Winforms and WPF for that I just need to write

```
System.IO.File.Encrypt("file.txt");
```

How to do the same in WinRT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, WinRT is designed for applications which run in a sandbox and have no direct filesystem access.

You'll probably need a non-WinRT (e.g. Win32 / .NET desktop API) service for direct filesystem access, and have the WinRT application communicate with the service.

Answer (score 4):

First I would never use System.IO.File.Encrypt to encrypt a file.
Second I would take a look at the following documentation: [Windows Runtime API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211377.aspx)
Third I would encrypt the file using a similar mehod describe [here](http://dotnetspeak.com/index.php/2011/11/encrypting-and-decrypting-data-in-winrt-2/) and [here](http://lukhezo.com/2011/11/06/encrypting-files-in-net-using-the-advanced-encryption-standard-aes/)

```
public MainWindow()
{
   InitializeComponent();

   byte[] encryptedPassword;

   // Create a new instance of the RijndaelManaged
   // class.  This generates a new key and initialization 
   // vector (IV).
   using (var algorithm = new RijndaelManaged())
   {
      algorithm.KeySize = 256;
      algorithm.BlockSize = 128;

      // Encrypt the string to an array of bytes.
      encryptedPassword = Cryptology.EncryptStringToBytes("Password", 
                                                    algorithm.Key, algorithm.IV);
   }

   string chars = encryptedPassword.Aggregate(string.Empty, 
                                         (current, b) => current + b.ToString());

Cryptology.EncryptFile(@"C:\Users\Ira\Downloads\test.txt", @"C:\Users\Ira\Downloads\encrypted_test.txt", chars);

Cryptology.DecryptFile(@"C:\Users\Ira\Downloads\encrypted_test.txt", @"C:\Users\Ira\Downloads\unencyrpted_test.txt", chars);
}
```

Comment: @Kip9000 - Some of your code changes are invalid and actually change the code. Your changes didn't improve anything, not sure the purpose of the change, the formatting was fine.

Comment: Code was formatted to make it fit without the scrollbar being visible. Changed the code to remove the long file paths because they are superfluous. The long file paths don't add anything to the code than making it harder to read.

Comment: @Kip9000 - I don't believe they are superfluous and I don't agree with the change.  I would rather delete the answer then allow it to be changed.

Comment: If you feel that much strongly about the change, do as you please. :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is going to require a little more work in WinRT.  Since most functions are asynchronous you will need some more boiler plate and you will be operating on streams and `IBuffer`s rather than files directly.  The crypto classes are in the [`Windows.Security.Cryptography`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br241404.aspx) namespace.

An example with an `IBuffer` can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br241562.aspx).

Comment: This won't be integrated with the filesystem in any way, for example things like multi-user access, revocation of access if password is force-changed, and recovery certificates won't work.

Comment: That is true, but the OP does not mention the need for integrated filesystem encryption, just encryption of a file.  This is possible using the aforementioned API.  Your post does mention the use of a service to access the filesystem which is fair and the right choice if the filesystem integration is a requirement.

Comment: I guess I interpret "do the same" as a requirement to use EFS.